# Binding an input and make the model persistant throughout the app in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Just want to enable a user to make searches from several points throughout the app screens.

How to persist the model?

The HTML for the search is as follows:

```
        <input 
            style="width:80%"
            ng-model="searchKeyword"
            id="search" 
            size="70" 
            type="search" 
            results="5" 
            placeholder="symptôme, maladie, etc." 
        />
```

This code snippet is located at several locations, including some partials.
Currently, it sounds like the value entered in one of these does not persist in all forms.

[EDIT] searchKeyword belongs to the controller scope.

[EDIT 2] Here is a fiddle that demonstrate the issue I want to fix in the very context it takes place in my app: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/abHFQ/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom directive.  [**DEMO-UPDATED**](http://plnkr.co/edit/w7M25A9b6CyDzLqF7H53?p=preview)

Seed of `js` code:

```
app.directive("search", function(){

  var search = {
    keyword : ""
  }

  return {

    restrict : "EA",

    scope: {},

    template : '<input \
            style="width:80%" \
            ng-model="search.keyword" \
            size="70" \
            type="search" \
            results="5" \
            placeholder="symptôme, maladie, etc." \
        />',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.search = search;
    }


  }
});
```

#### UPDATE

To make use of the keyword in controller - just store it as a `value`.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, searchVal) {
  $scope.search = searchVal;
});

app.value("searchVal", {
  keyword : "I am in controller - no problem!"
})

app.directive("searchDir", function(searchVal){

  return {

    restrict : "EA",

    scope: {},

    template : '<input \
            style="width:80%" \
            ng-model="search.keyword" \
            size="70" \
            type="search" \
            results="5" \
            placeholder="symptôme, maladie, etc." \
        />',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.search = searchVal;
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks @artur grzesiak Using directive is the only option I have?

Comment: It is not the **only** option, but *imho* the most elegant. But why? What is wrong with using a directive?

Comment: I forgot to mention I need the searchKeyword to be in the controller scope as it is widely used in controller methods.

Comment: Hi @artur grziak I just published a fiddle that demonstrate the issue in the very context it takes place.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Modified your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abHFQ/18/) by including approach from my plnkr.

Comment: Thanks @artur grzesiak.I marked your answer as accepted, as it's one way to do it. Though digging further into this, I opted for a Factory, with no additional directive. I kept mu original code, simply added a app.factory("Search") which simply return a structure where my members are stored. Factory also keeps members persistent throughout routes. I can't grasp the very difference between values and factory.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca values are meant to store simple objects, whereas with factories you can make advantage of functional closure. (Apart from that they are pretty the same). Directive may be used on top of value/factory/service in order to provide consistent 'feel' across the application. In case of simple input it maybe an overkill. I used it as initially it was not clear that you wanted to make use of the value in controllers.